# using Apache HttpClient in a new thread, I don't know if it finished running

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, httpclient

I faced a strange problem. I hope someone would find out the reason.
code:

```
    public static void asyncSend(final RoomNotification notification, final int retryTimes) {

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean finish = false;
            try {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                String messageString = mapper.writeValueAsString(notification);
                logger.info("json to send to Hipchat :{}", messageString);
    #1          Content content = Request.Post("https://api.hipchat.com/v2/room/<hidden>/notification?auth_token=<hidden>")
                        .bodyString(messageString, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .execute().returnContent();
    #2          logger.info("Hipchat return:{}", content.asString());
                finish = true;
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
    #3          logger.info("send Hipchat {}:\n{}", finish ? "successfully" : "unsuccessfully", notification.message);
                if (finish) {
                    return;
                }
                //如果失败，且还有重试次数就重新发送
                if (retryTimes > 0) {
                    logger.info("retry sending Hipchat, retry times remain:{}\nmessage:{}", retryTimes, notification.getMessage());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10000); //重试前暂停10秒
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    asyncSend(notification, retryTimes - 1);
                } else {
                    logger.info("no retry times remain, finally send Hipchat unsuccessfully.\nmessage:{}", notification.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
}
```

The problem is that, sometimes the line at neither #2 nor #3 would be run. is that mean the thread crashed without exception, or the line at #1 never finished running?
The code at line #1 is reference from [Apache Httpcomponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/quickstart.html).

I analysised the log just now, the output shows below:

```
[wwwuser@mixi-mantou ~]$ grep "json to send to Hipchat" tomcat-mixi/logs/catalina.out | wc -l
216
[wwwuser@mixi-mantou ~]$ grep "send Hipchat successfully" tomcat-mixi/logs/catalina.out | wc -l
197
[wwwuser@mixi-mantou ~]$ grep "send Hipchat unsuccessfully" tomcat-mixi/logs/catalina.out | wc -l
14
```

So this problem occured 5(216-197-14) times.
Wish someone could help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you received an Error so severe that the finally block could not execute, most likely the problem is that the Request.Post never returned.

There are several ways you can find out what is happening. All of these should be done while the program is still running, but all threads doing the call should have ended.

1. Check for open TCP connections: under both Windows or Unix use "netstat" in a shell or command prompt. This command shows you all current TCP connections between your computer and the server. Check whether there are more open connection than there should be.
2. Create a full stack dump: under unix find out the PID of the Java process (using "ps"), then issue a "kill -QUIT [pid]" (replacing [pid] with the PID you found). Under Windows it can be more complicated: If you started the Java program from a command line, press CTRL+BREAK. Or you could use jstack (see https://blogs.oracle.com/pcmreddy/entry/using_jstack_on_windows). All this writes to stdout a stack trace of all running threads. Check whether for threads that are still in the Request.Post call.

You can do this also while your application is still executing. But then you have to distinguish the hanging threads from those running ok and just happen to be in the Request.Post call. It might help to check the TCP connections and/or stack traces a few times, with some seconds in between, to see what has changed. You might also give your threads names containing the start time, to easier detect long-running threads in the thread dumps.

Comment: I used jstack, and find that some threads were staying at a method of AppacheHttpClient for a long time. It seems that they were waiting for being awaken. I think it's a bug of AppacheHttpClient. Finally I gived up this mechanism and used nodejs to implement this.